# Adding an input to a pipelined command

Tags: input

I use a pipelined command in an alias to start a docker server (e.g `alias ent="echo -e '\n';docker-compose up|grep --color ERROR"`).

The server sometimes asks me a question, to which I should input <kbd>y</kbd> or <kbd>n</kbd>. I always enter <kbd>y</kbd>.

How can I add it to my pipelined command?

Comment: It depends somewhat on _what_ it is that asks the question and from where it's expecting to read the answer.  Is it reading from the standard input of `docker-command`, you could possibly just use `echo 'y' | docker-compose ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a perfect job for the `yes` command!

From the manpage:

> DESCRIPTION
>          Repeatedly output a line with all specified STRING(s), or 'y'.

That means that a simple `yes` outputs `y` indefinitely.

I suppose is `docker-compose up` which need "yes" input, so you can use something like

```
alias ent="echo -e '\n';yes | docker-compose up | grep --color ERROR"
```